# How to connect a SAS PCIe Card to a Tape Drive?

Tags: backup, sas, tape

I have the PCIe Card: Highpoint 4322 which is supposed to be a PCIe SAS Card with HBA which comes with two SFF-8088 ports - [manufacturer's website](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/cs-series_rr4300.htm)

I also have a tape drive Tandberg Data 3513-LTO Ultrium LTO-4 with the following specs - [manufacturer's website](http://www.tandbergdata.com/us/index.cfm/products/tape-drives/lto-drives/lto-4-hh/)

> LTO-4 HH - External SAS tape drive, Symantec Backup Exec QS Single
>   server, Quick Start Guide, Warranty Card, 1 data Cartridge, US/Jpn
>   Power Cord, EUR power cord

---

I manage to install it on Windows 10 with the driver and the management and I can't manage to get the Tape Drive to show up.

Here are a few screenshots taken in the management that shows all the possibilities. I can also access these fonctionalities right after boot, before than Windows boot up and it doesn't change anything.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### My questions are the following:

- Is my SAS card compatible with my Tape Drive ? If not what sould I buy (lower than 70$).
- If this SAS card is compatible, how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Tape drives do not go in RAID arrays - you should try with some tape drive software such as BackupAssist to connect to the drive (just an example, not a recommendation, I don't use that software but it came up with a quick Google search).

Does the drive show up in Device Manager?  If so, should work fine with backup software that supports tape drives.